# Angularjs remove event listener when element is removed from DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, listener

I would like to invoke a function when target element has been deleted. I tried something like below, and it seems like working well. Is it okay to use this code? (since there is no reference document about 'remove' listener on neither angularjs nor jquery)

```
angular.element( event.currentTarget)
     .on( 'remove', function() {
         // some code
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS framework intercepts jQuery `.remove` operations and dispatches a `$destroy` event.

From the Docs:

> ## Events
>
> `$destroy` - AngularJS intercepts all jqLite/jQuery's DOM destruction apis and fires this event on all DOM nodes being removed. This can be used to clean up any 3rd party bindings to the DOM element before it is removed.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.element API Reference - extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)

Answer (score 0):

You can find related doc on AngularJS page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element, also on JQuery's API page https://api.jquery.com/remove/

How about this?
https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for deleting element method. need a document that refer 'on remove listener' when an element has been deleted.